# Area between curves $r=5\sin(3\theta)$ and $r=8\sin(3\theta)$

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

So I was studying for a test and came across the following prompt:

"What is the total area between the polar curves $r=5\sin(3\theta)$ and $r=8\sin(3\theta)$?"

I guess I'm a bit confused about what the bounds of my integral might look like here. I understand that the setup for the area integral is as follows:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_a^b(f(\theta)^2-g(\theta)^2)d\theta$$
but I'm a bit confused about how I'd go about finding my bounds for this integral. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: In general, bounds can be found by finding points of intersection. Here, the curves intersect at the origin, so the candidates for bounds are when $r=0$, i.e. when $\sin(3\theta)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that each curve represents a set of three equally spaced pedals with each pedal subtending a polar angle of $\frac\pi3$.
Thus, the area is
$$\frac{3}{2}\int_0^{\frac\pi3} (f(\theta)^2-g(\theta)^2)d\theta
= \frac{3}{2}\int_0^{\frac\pi3} (64\sin^2(3\theta)-25\sin^2(3\theta))d\theta=\frac{39\pi}4
$$

Comment: Do you mean petals?

Comment: @SomeGuy, yes...

Answer (score 1):

Due to centrality of alignment and polar symmetry $ \theta \text{ varies between ( 0 ,} \pi/3) $ for both.